# What does the clang++ -c flag do?

Tags: c++, shell, unix, clang, clang++

What does the **-c** flag do in the following command?

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -stdlib=libc++ -isystem testing/gtest-1.7.0/include -Itesting/gtest-1.7.0 -pthread -c testing/gtest-1.7.0/src/gtest-all.cc
```

I've looked for the flag in the documentation (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html), as well as in the help message (`clang -cc1 --help`)...can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP cound not be bothered to read the man pages.

Comment: @MartinJames see my comments below the answers.

Comment: `-c` makes the compiler _stop_ before the _link_ phase ([from](https://blog.ecosta.dev/en/tech/cpp-modules-with-clang)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-c` flag is used to tell the compiler you don't want to build a program (link together into an executable), just compile this particular file into an object file - typically producing a file called something.o or something.obj - in this case `gteger-all.cc`

(Note that this flag is common with nearly all compilers available - from Turbo C from 1990's to the latest versions of MS, Gnu and LLVM/Clang)

Answer (score 3):

`man clang++`

```
OPTIONS
   Stage Selection Options
       -E  Run the preprocessor stage.

       -fsyntax-only
           Run the preprocessor, parser and type checking stages.

       -S  Run the previous stages as well as LLVM generation and optimization stages and target-specific code generation, producing an assembly file.

       -c  Run all of the above, plus the assembler, generating a target ".o" object file.
```

Comment: This description alone doesn’t compare the -c flag versus default (no flag). Obviously clang compiles, so what difference -c makes? It doesn’t clarify that -c makes compiler not to generate executable file, but to generate object file instead. I am sure it says it somewhere in the man page, but it is usually buried in lots of text and you cannot easily search and find it unless you read everything. (People usually avoid because it is long and understanding everything need knowledge at the level of a master-level compiler course: just to find a commonly used flag).

Comment: In fact man page does clarify it: "       **no stage selection option**
              If no stage selection option is specified, all stages above are run, and the linker is run to
              combine the results into an executable or shared library.
"

Answer (score 1):

**man clang** is your friend!

```
OPTIONS
   Stage Selection Options
       -E  Run the preprocessor stage.

       -fsyntax-only
           Run the preprocessor, parser and type checking stages.

       -S  Run the previous stages as well as LLVM generation and optimization
           stages and target-specific code generation, producing an assembly
           file.

       -c  Run all of the above, plus the assembler, generating a target ".o"
           object file.
```